# Uploading large files with WebService::Dropbox

Tags: perl, dropbox, large-files

Can someone here give me some example code for using the
[`WebService::Dropbox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WebService::Dropbox) module
to upload files bigger than 1GB?

I followed the instructions and successfully uploaded files less than 150MB but I don't understand how to upload larger files.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What happens if you try uploading a large file? Is there an error? Does it respond with a specific code, or does the connection close unexpectedly? Please [edit] your question and provide answers to my questions as well as the code you've written to upload that file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The
[module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/WebService::Dropbox#upload_session($path,-$content-%5B,-%5C%25optional_params,-$limit%5D))
says this about the `update` method

> Do not use this to upload a file larger than 150 MB. Instead, create an upload session with upload_session/start.

And this is presumably why you have mentioned 150MB in your question.

The documentation for `upload_session` has this

> Uploads large files by upload_session API
>
> ```
> # File Handle  
> my $content = IO::File->new('./mysql.dump', '<');  
>
> my $result = $dropbox->upload_session($path, $content);  
>
> my $result = $dropbox->upload_session($path, $content, {  
>     mode => 'add',  
>     autorename => JSON::true,  
>     mute => JSON::false  
> });
> ```

Note that, just like the documentation for `upload`, those two examples of calling `upload_session` are *alternatives*, and you should choose the second only if you have special requirements that require non-default option values

There is also no need to use `IO::File` to open a file: the standard Perl `open` call will work fine, and you should add a `:raw` layer whether you are using `IO::File` or not, like this

```
open my $content, '<:raw', './mysql.dump' or die $!
```

There is also no need for `JSON::true` and `JSON::false`: a simple `1` and `0` will do fine

This is pretty much identical to the `upload` use case, which you say you have working fine. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: In my case I know how to upload file on sites  but its first time I'm trying with this so I'm not comfortable to understand the 2nd part of that documentation. My English is not that good that get that easily. You can say I have $content =  $x->{dir}/$fname already available with completely available in my package file that I am using that to post data in a form for upload. So can you suggest me how should I write that up for their code.  I just started learning perl just few days back so just trying my level best.

Comment: @alex: Please edit the question to show how you have successfully uploaded smaller files.

Comment: Thanks for your help m8 but dev helped me this is what  I was looking for https://github.com/s-aska/dropbox-api-command/blob/master/script/dropbox-api#L1133-L1233 he got it what exactly I was looking for!

Comment: @alex: That's a very long-winded solution to your problem: it would be much better to use a simple `upload_session` call. And it's very rude of you to ignore our advice and questions and go elsewhere for help without telling us. You've just wasted hours of several people's time. If you have a solution then please at least write up an answer of your own, including the final code that you are using and not just a link to an external site.

Comment: Hey sorry for that but I failed to make it more than 150mb (my mistake was just this  "")so we dropped idea of Dropbox and since I'm modifying someone else code I'm bound to his licence terms so can't post code :(